# Only the first MVC ErrorHandler attribute should run

Tags: error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use the MVC custom errors so that only unexpected controller errors get logged.

I've created a 'HandleAndLogError' attribute for doing this, it inherits from HandleErrorAttribute. I only want the HandleAndLogError attribute to run if the exception is not covered by other error handler attributes on methods.

For example:

```
[HandleAndLogError(View = "Error", Order = -1)]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HandleErrorWithoutLogging(ExceptionType = typeof(InvalidOperationException), View = "Error", Order = 0)]
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When SomeAction raises an InvalidOperationException I only want HandleErrorWithoutLogging to handle it.
What happens though is that HandleErrorWithoutLogging runs and then HandleAndLogError runs straight after.

Is there a simple way of making the first error handler prevent others from running?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out where I've gone wrong, it turned out to be embarassingly simple. There is an ExceptionHandled flag in the context passed to the handler that gets set to true when the base code runs. I just needed to wrap my code with an if block.

For anyone wondering, this is what I ended up with:

```
public class HandleErrorWithLoggingAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            base.OnException(filterContext);

            if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```